# Exe + .DLL + вызыватель Bat => один EXE

Tags: bat, exe, visual-studio, c++, dll

Есть 4 файла:

1. Главный Exe
2. Два .DLL от Visual Studio которые необходимы для работы Exe-шника
3. Bat-вызыватель, который передает параметры на вход Exe-шнику.

Как все это собрать в один Exe, при его запуске должен запускаться батник, вызывающий Exe-шник, который инклудит библиотеки, но все обязательно собрать в один файл!

Answer (score 4):

Ну если у вас батник чисто что бы передавать параметры то просто пропишите эти параметры в самой программе и ненужен будет батник.

Так же если я правильно понял то DLL это рунтайм библиотеки от VS, можно в настройках проекта сделать что бы эти библиотеки подключались статические, а не динамические и они будут в самом exe.

Comment: У меня нет исходников,только бинарник, что делать?